# Insert class when slidetoggle is activated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

Struggling with where to start on this one, apologies for not much code.

Using slide toggle to display a `div` when `a` is clicked.

`a` currently has a background image with a defined position. I've created a sprite image, so that when the link is clicked, the background position will change to show a downwards pointing arrow (like a typical expanding list.)

How can I build into the function that when `a` is clicked, a class of `arrowDown` is added?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubPve/5/)

I'd like to add a class to this link:

```
<a>See opening times</a>
```

CSS needing to be added using classname `arrowDown`

```
a.arrowDown
{
    background-position: 2px -9px;
    }
```

Function:

```
$('.timeList a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toggleClass` method:

```
$('.timeList a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('arrowDown').next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```